# Displaying results using custom HTML for Select2QuerySetSequenceView in django-autocomplete-light

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light 3.2.1 with Django 1.10.
What I am building is an autocomplete that gives results from 2 different models in custom HTML (as I want to display thumbnails).

[The documentation](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#displaying-results-using-custom-html) shows how to display autocomplete results with custom HTML when using Select2QuerySetView and get_result_label(self, item), and this works great when building an autocomplete which gives results from 1 model only.

However, I am using Select2QuerySetSequenceView because I need to display results from multiple models. get_result_label(self, item) doesn't seem to be working with Select2QuerySetSequenceView and I've tried jumping into the source code but still cannot figure out how to display results with custom HTML.

Appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: In my case, it is not working with even one model, although I implemented  `get_result_label(self, item)`and added `attrs={'data-html': True}` to the form. It shows the html tag in raw format (`<a href..`), not interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a little more customization if you load your styles.css file after the dal select2 files.  If you load {{ form.media }} in your template you can also try loading styles.css after that.

Good luck finding a true answer, I'm looking for one myself.